# Arraylist not displaying the right output

Tags: arraylist

My main class code

```
{
     ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
     Scanner file = new Scanner(kk.class.getResourceAsStream("product.txt"));
     while (file.hasNextLine()) { 
        String[] sp = file.nextLine().split(",");
        // extract item number, description, price and type
        itemNum = Integer.parseInt(sp[0]);
        des = sp[1];
        price = Integer.parseInt(sp[2]);
        Item objt = new Item(itemNum, des, price); // Creating a new object
        items.add(objt); // Adding it to the list
     }
     System.out.println(items);
}
```

output I am getting

[dada.Item@4a5d4a62, dada.Item@32be8e12, dada.Item@7c6159c4, dada.Item@5b4c92a7, dada.Item@3040c5,

My item class code

```
 private int itemNum = 0;
private String des = "";
private int price = 0;

public Item(int i, String d, int p) {
    itemNum = i;
    des = d;
    price = p;
}
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What have you tried yet?

Comment: I want the arrayList to store the data from my text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the `Item` reference's address instead of the fields inside your `Item` object. You have print the fields inside each `Item` object by looping through them.

Replace this line

```
System.out.println(items);
```

with

```
for(Item i : items) 
{
    System.out.println(i.getItemNum()+" "+i.getDes()+" "+i.getPrice());
}
```

Change the class so that you could access your private fields

```
private int itemNum = 0;
private String des = "";
private int price = 0;

public Item(int i, String d, int p) {
    itemNum = i;
    des = d;
    price = p;
}

public void setItemNum(int itemNum) {
    this.itemNum = itemNum;
}
public int getItemNum() {
    return itemNum;
}

public void setDes(String des) {
    this.des = des;
}
public String getDes() {
    return des;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code still not getting the correct output. Example of the output I got 
dada.Item@32be8e12

dada.Item@7c6159c4

dada.Item@5b4c92a7

Comment: How should your output look like? I think you're storing objects in your array. Please post your required output here. Also show your Item class file

Comment: @MeroRai I have changed my answer, see if it works. But I answered based on assumption that your Item class has public fields itemNum, des, price. I could help you solve it if you could show your Item class.